# In-App Billing Library for Android Game

Tags: android, mobile, economy, microtransactions

I'm trying to add in-app purchases into my Android game and it having some trouble figuring my around the Google Play Billing. Can anyone refer me to a good open source reference for how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across an open source resource that simplifies in-app billing on Android. Take a look at http://soom.la. They also have a reference app that shows you how to use it. Here is the [sample app on Github](https://github.com/soomla/android-store/tree/master/SoomlaAndroidExamples/MuffinRushExample/src/com/soomla/example/muffinRush)

I'm using Unity, they also provide a free plugin on the Unity Asset Store: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/6103.